# Java Applet: Invocation Target Exception when loading an image

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet

I have a Java applet which works fine when is runned on Eclipse. However, when is embed in the browser, I get an invocation target exception and no trace is shown.

I have started to write the code step by step and trying in the navigator and it seems to be an error related to the loading of images (I have a button where I want to show an icon).

This is the code of the button to show the icon (the class is called EsqNO and the image is in a folder call "images" at the same level that the java class). If I delete this line of code, the applet works fine in the browser.

```
buttonInfo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(EsqNO.class.getResource("/images/iconoInformacion.png")));
```

How can I do to make it works in Eclipse and in the browser (and see the icon)?

Comment: Side note: unless you are doing this for "work"; and your boss told you so: there is no point in learning about Java applets. That is "dead technology"; and nobody (except people who are forced by their company to do so) is using it anymore. If you have a choice, learn about Swing or JavaFx.

Comment: I know, but that´s not the problem I asking about.

Comment: I know. But the thing with "dead technology" might also impact how many people will be looking into such questions. My "generic hint" here: are you following some sort of tutorial? Meaning: do not try to get such stuff up and running "by yourself and trial and error". Get a good book or online resource that covers the complete process; and follow that.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @Jägermeister *"If you have a choice, learn about Swing or JavaFx."* The Swing equivalent of `java.applet.Applet` is a `javax.swing.JApplet`. Though I agree on the general idea that the OP should avoid (both) applets in general as well as anything based on AWT.

Comment: *"Invocation Target Exception when loading an image"* Almost forgot. That exception stacktrace usually has a 'caused by' part. Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: Java console is empty. That´s why I don´t understand what´s happening.

Comment: Is there another way to put an icon inside a button?